# VisualHg and Visual Studio 2010 Performance Issue

Tags: visual-studio, performance, visual-studio-2010, mercurial, visualhg

My team recently started using VisualHg, with TortoiseHg, and Visual Studio 2010.  For a member of my team, and myself, using the combination of **VisualHg** and **Visual Studio 2010** causes our CPU performance to spike to around 50%!

Sometimes by restarting Visual Studio 2010, the performance issue will go away, but sometimes it comes back.  Any thoughts?  I think this is a VisualHg *intermittent* bug--it's inconsistent.

Comment: Have you considered asking this on the discussion board for the VisualHG addin?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its related to anti-virus. From the [TortoiseHg FAQ](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/faq.html):

> Is Mercurial on Windows compatible with the index service and virus scanners?
>
> No. Like TortoiseSVN, [we recommend](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2010-January/029680.html) to turn off the indexing service on the working copies and repositories, and exclude them from virus scans.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a VisualHg bug.

In my team we've been using the exact same setup for quite some time. We've had performance issues and freezes, but the complaints stopped once we've completely turned off IntelliSense for C++ projects (Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > Disable database...). The Visual Assist does its job perfectly.

Also, make sure:

- You have SP1 installed. Before SP1, VS2010 was completely unusable due to crashes and freezes.
- No antivirus software or indexing service running on the projects files.

As a side note, instead of using VisualHg, I can suggest you to create your your macros to run the THG and bind them to the file's context menus. It's really the same as using VisualHG, but no third-party addin is used. I've been using this technique when THG2.0 came out and VisualHG hadn't supported it.

Update: Also, I have just recently stumbled upon another issue with VS2010+THG. The problem was with the .sdf file, which is generated by VS2010 near the solution file. I use thg a lot with opened solution, and VS constantly asks me to reload the projects. During one such update, I got my .sdf so corrupted that VS freezed for a minute while opening the project, and later it couldn't open it at all. Deleting the .sdf helped completely, so you might try that too.